failing to deploy transction in ganache
const ethers = require("ethers");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

async function main() {
  try {
    const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545");
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(
      "0x82da6c2af8d03a9a4e11fdd951623580deaf49f549aa2ad31c3416ab60f6d5b3",
      provider
    );

    const abi = fs.readFileSync(
      "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.abi",
      "utf8"
    );
    const binary = fs.readFileSync(
      "./SimpleStorage_sol_SimpleStorage.bin",
      "utf8"
    );

    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, binary, wallet);
    console.log("Deploying, please hang on...");

    const contract = await contractFactory.deploy({
      gasLimit: 6721975,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
    });

    console.log("Deployment Transaction:", contract.deployTransaction);

    console.log("Waiting for the contract to be mined...");
    await contract.deployTransaction.wait(1); // Wait for 1 block confirmation
    console.log("Contract deployed successfully!");

    // Call the `retrieve` function on the deployed contract
    console.log("Calling retrieve method...");
    const favNumber = await contract.retrieve();
    console.log("Favorite number:", favNumber.toString());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during deployment or function call:", error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main(); 

This my code and I check abi and binary all good to go,but when i try to node deploy.js in terminal it shows the following error -
Deploying, please hang on...
Deployment Transaction: undefined
Waiting for the contract to be mined...
Error during deployment or function call: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wait')
    at main (/Users/wasimchoudhary/ethersjs blockchain/ether-ssstorage/deploy.js:32:38)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Got. stuck here for days due to environment probs.
I was trying to deploy my contract through local environment ganache cli or ganche gui
